# forced file to download instead showing in the browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I just want to download file when button gets clicked. I am using `top.location.href` in jQuery to start downloading but this code work fine on localhost, but when I try this on server then instead of start downloading it display the file as text in the browser.

This is what I am doing :

```
$('#download_button').click(function(){

    var filepath = $(this).attr("data-src");
    // filepath = library/files/filename.git

    top.location.href = filepath; // open download dialog box
});
```

The above code start downloading my custom file that contain 'xml' data by opening a dialog box on localhost but this code not work on server.

Is anything I am doing wrong?

I tried to find out the problem but everyone says add these line of code in your hyaccess file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:git)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

But I never found htaccess file on my server. Can I create a new file with in my directory and add this code into it ?

Comment: Just create a new file and name it `.htaccess`. This will do it. Its just a plain text file. Then you can add whatever you want.

Comment: Theoretically, you can create a new "`.htaccess`" file in the directory, yes. Although, if you have multiple .htaccess files in your web-server this could cause unexpected conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
$('#download_button').click(function(){

    var filepath = $(this).attr("data-src");
    // filepath = library/files/filename.git
                                                                                               var url = 'library/files/download.php';
    var inputfied =  '<input type="text" name="filepath" value="' + filepath + '" />';
    var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="POST" >' +inputfied +'</form>');
    $('body').append(form);
    $(form).submit();
});
```

and use this page `download.php`

```
<?php
$file=$_POST['filepath'] ;//file location;
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTML5 download attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_a_download.asp)

```
<a href="/something.git" download="name-of-file">Click to download</a>
```

Comment: Be aware that not all browsers support this attribute, however. See [this page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) for more details. **NOTE:** This comment is for anyone attempting to use this unaware of HTML5 compatibility.